# Vtiger CRM extensions and add-ons

Tags: windows, localserver, vtigercrm

I need to install certain extensions on my local system and get access to additional options in existing modules.

Initially when it was installed on a linux system server, I had to install an ioncube loader in the setup in order to get these additional access. After successful installation of ioncube loader, I got access to some more options like an **Extension Pack** drop down list and **Field Formula** option in the workflow action drop down list. Now when I have installed vtiger in my local Windows server, I am not getting these options even after installing ioncube loader successfully. Can anyone help me as to where I am going wrong or guide me on how to get those options?

Comment: which extensions are that? have you tried asking to the extension's developer?

Comment: It's called an Extension Pack for Vtiger

Comment: Extension Pack seems to be a subscription service (https://www.vtexperts.com/premium/). If you are subscribed, you can contact directly vtexperts for help. If you aren't, you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: I have just signed up for a 15 day trial to check if it meets my needs.

Comment: Then I suggest you to contact vtexperts support, so before subscribing you can check how client support works.